# Struts 2 jquery plugin id for visible input in sj:autocompleter

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, autocomplete, struts2-jquery

When creating an struts 2 jquery auto completer, the tag creates a hidden and a visible input.

If we set the id like below:

```
<sj:autocompleter id="sample/>
```

The id will be assigned to hidden input. Is there any way we can assign the id to visible input. The generated html for this input is:

```
<input class="s2j-combobox-input ui-autocomplete-input">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a visible input element using jQuery and use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function on the element(s).

```js
$(function(){
  $(".s2j-combobox-input.ui-autocomplete-input").attr("id", value);
});
```